# NodeJS : How can i display an error message in a Login Page if the authentication fails

Tags: node.js, passport.js

```
app.post("/login",passport.authenticate("local",{          
  successRedirect: "/loginconfirm",   
  failureRedirect: "/login"            
}),                                                                                     function(req, res){
});
```

can you please help me??????

Comment: did you try. res.json or res.send?